# We have $(x^2+y^2)^2-3(x^2+y^2)+1=0$. What is the value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> We have $(x^2+y^2)^2-3(x^2+y^2)+1=0$. What is the value of
> $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?
>
> $1)-\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^2}\qquad\qquad2)-\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^3}\qquad\qquad3)\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}\qquad\qquad4)\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Here is my approach:

We have a quadratic equation in $x^2+y^2$. So $x^2+y^2=\frac{3\pm\sqrt5}{2}$ (RHS is a constant). Taking differentiate with respect to $x$,

$$2x+2yy'=0\Rightarrow\quad y'=\frac{-x}{y}$$
$$2+2y'^2+2yy''=0\Rightarrow \quad y''=\frac{-y'^2}{y}\Rightarrow y''=\frac{-x^2}{y^3}$$
**Edit:**

The second option can be written as $-(\frac{x^2}{y^3}+\frac{1}y)$. It seems it is the correct answer. But why I missed $-\frac1y$ in this approach?

Comment: for some reason you forgot the $2$ (the extra constant from differentiating $2x$) when you rearranged for $y''$. If you keep in mind $x^2+y^2$ is a constant you can keep multiplying or dividing by factors of it at a cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you just made a small mistake at the last step: from $2+2y'^2+2yy''=0$ we find that
$$y''=-\frac{1+y'^2}{y}=-\frac{1+(-x/y)^2}{y}=-\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You missed the $-\dfrac{1}{y} $ because you forgot the $2$ on the left-side of the equation.
$$ y'' = \dfrac{-2(y')^2 \color{red}{-2}}{2y} \ne \dfrac{-2(y')^2 }{2y} $$